# deepspeech: how to make a prediction using checkpoints

Tags: python, mozilla, speech-to-text

I have a quite noob question.
I train deepspeech model on gpu, checkpoints are saved to the folder ‘checkpoints’.
If I interrupt a training process, how can I use checkpoints of model to make predictions?
For example, I want to see what model predicts to some wav-file.
I need to generate csv-file which describes this wav-file? And how to check a model?

Thanks a lot for your attention, I will appreciate any help or link.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The parameter  --one_shot_infer  where you specify the path to the wav file was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have exported your model using `--export_dir` to somewhere. If you did then you might find a file with extension `.pb` or `.pbmm` . using that you can perform inference. For more details visit official documentation [here](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech). 
you can perform inference using the below command from linux or mac. 
`$ deepspeech --model /path/to/model/ --audio /path/to/audio/ --alphabet /path/to/alphabet/ --lm /path/to/langauge/model/ --trie /path/to/trie/file/` .
to perform python inference please refer [client.py](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/blob/master/native_client/python/client.py) in the same project repo.